# Fix Build Failed on React-Native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm a newbie to react native. I started a new project and followed all the steps. I had Android Studio before and I started the emulator with it. After running npx react-native run-android command I get this error. This is the

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libbetter.so, libc++_shared.so, libevent-2.1.so, libevent_core-2.1.so, libevent_extra-2.1.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libflipper.so, libfolly_futures.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes-executor-common-debug.so, libhermes-executor-common-release.so, libhermes-executor-debug.so, libhermes-executor-release.so, libhermes-inspector.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjsc.so, libjscexecutor.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactconfig.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactnativeutilsjni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_modal.so, librrc_progressbar.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_slider.so, librrc_switch.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textin
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
31 actionable tasks: 31 executed
Note: E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\android\app\src\debug\java\com\rndasar\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\android\app\src\debug\java\com\rndasar\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s

    at makeError (E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\Coding\React Native\RNdasar\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says no devices connected.

Means there is no emulator or a device connected to your system.

1. If you have an emulator please run it before running react native app. If not please create an emulator first.

Follow this link to create one : [create emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

2. If you want to run it on your phone. Attach it with a cable and turn on usb debugging on your phone.

Hope this solves your problem